# Retrieve complete callback function off an element's animate

Tags: jquery

How can I access and change the callback function that will be invoked when a jQuery animation ends by manipulating the element being animated only?

Please see this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9Lb8bejt/3/).

```
$("#box").animate({
  "left": "200px",
}, 10000, function() {
  // complete callback
  $("#status").html("Done");
});

setTimeout(function(){
  // how to get the complete callback off $("#box) above here? 
  // note the callback function is being called here, 
  // but I want the animation to finish but don't call the callback function until later
  $("#box").stop(true,true);
}, 2000);

setTimeout(function(){
  // call the complete callback here
}, 4000);
```

I want to stop and finish the animation but skipping calling the complete callback until later.

I understand I can assign the callback function to a variable and then access this variable later on, but I'm working on a large project and wish to manipulate the callback function by manipulating the element only.

Comment: so it looks like you want to stop the animation at 2 seconds and then continue it 2 seconds later. why not just use two animations?

Comment: I'm trying to get the animation to complete but hold off on calling the complete callback function until later on. If you see the jsfiddle I posted, when stop is invoked in the animated element, the animation finishes but the callback function also gets called.

Comment: Also, I'm dealing with a large project with multiple animations going on, so I'm trying to find a way to access the callback property using the element only. I can access the animated elements by doing $("*:animated"), but then I don't know how to manipulate those elements' callback functions.

Comment: how about you leave the callback empty and call `$('#status').html('Done')` in the second `setTimeout`?

Comment: That's a good point, but this would be tricky when dealing with multiple animations going on. There ought to be a way to retrieve and change the callback function though because jQuery has to have it to call it once the animation completes.

Comment: As in -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/9Lb8bejt/4/

Comment: @adeneo: close, but 2 seconds was for demo purpose. What I'm trying to accomplish is a pause/resume functionality in the project so once the user clicks on resume, the callback function of the animations will be invoked, so I won't know how long to delay the callback functions for.

Comment: Then you're going about it the wrong way. It's not easy to just pause stuff, and have it resume, but I would look into Greensocks GSAP, it has built in ways to handle this

Comment: Thanks for the link @adeneo. The project is already built though, so refactoring it now is quite complicated. I understand to pause/resume jQuery animations is hard (impossible?), that's why I'm looking for a solution to just call the callback function but leave the animation running.

Comment: I think I can try to override jQuery's animate function that once called, it creates a property on the element with the callback function. This way I can access it later.